# Replace 0 / 1 columns with true / false factors

Tags: r

I'd like to programmatically convert columns with the values of 0 or 1 into factors. I was thinking about doing this by checking for the distinct values in each column and then using `as.factor` in the case that the distinct values are 0 and 1.

I'm wondering if there might be a smarter way of doing this. I plan to use this within a function.

I'd like to replace 0 / 1 factors with true / false factors instead

This is my data

```
credit$int_coded_factor <-
  rep(c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0), 100)
```

I'd like the output to be equal to this

```
credit$int_coded_factor <-
  rep(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 100)
```

I'd like something that I can apply programmatically without knowing the name of the column

Comment: It would be helpful if you add an example along with expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% mutate(across(where(~all(. %in% c(0, 1))), factor))
#Using `mutate_if` : 
#df1 <- df %>% mutate_if(~all(. %in% c(0, 1)), factor)
str(df1)

#'data.frame':  6 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ a: int  0 1 2 3 4 5
# $ b: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 1 2
# $ c: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = 0:5, b = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), c = letters[1:6])
str(df)
#'data.frame':  6 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ a: int  0 1 2 3 4 5
# $ b: num  1 0 0 1 0 1
# $ c: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
```

Comment: Can we replace these types of factors with TRUE / FALSE?

Comment: This was super helpful! I updated my question because this answer helped clarify my thoughts

Comment: You can do `df %>% mutate(across(where(~all(. %in% c(0, 1))), factor, labels = c(FALSE, TRUE)))` to replace 1/0 with `TRUE`/`FALSE`

Comment: Awesome! This is great

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. If you just have a data frame with specific columns you want to turn to factors, this should work:

```
num <- floor(runif(10000, max = 2))

fact <- as.factor(num)
```

Note that `num` is just dummy data.

If you want to identity which columns fit this description, the answer by Ronak Shah should work.